# How to convert shape file type from polyline to polygon?

Tags: gis, polygon, shapes, polyline, shapefile

I have a shape file whose file type is polyline. But I want convert it to polygon. Is it possible with free sources? How can I convert shape file type from polyline to polygon?

Comment: Could you share what GIS software you're using?  A Google search of "convert polylines polygons" (without the quotes) brings up lots of solutions, but they are all dependent on what GIS software you're using.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done pretty easily in python with the help of the [PySAL](http://pysal.org/1.2/users/tutorials/index.html) library.

For example given a shapefile named "tst.shp" with two polylines,
[image: Two Polylines in QGIS]

We can open the shapefile convert the polylines to polygons and write out a new shapefile.

```
>>> import pysal
>>> shps = pysal.open('tst.shp','r')
>>> o = pysal.open('tst_polygons.shp','w')
>>> for polyline in shps:
...     verts = polyline.vertices
...     if verts[0] != verts[-1]: #make sure the polylines are closed rings
...         verts = verts+verts[0:1]
...     o.write(pysal.cg.Polygon(verts))
...
>>> o.close()
```

Now we have polygons,
[image: Two Polygons in QGIS]

If you need a way to accomplish this without programming, try asking your questions at http://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks for reply. i have seen this one in google. but with c# (not python) is it possible?

Comment: There are probably a number of Shapefile reader/writers for C# out there. If not you can find the Shapefile specification here, http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf

Comment: The differences between the Polyline and Polygon types are minimal. The most important thing is your rings need to be closed. If they are, you could probably just tweek the type flag for each shape and in the main header to get back a Polygon shapefile.